# How to get data before update script into temp table? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have an UPDATE script like:

```
update public.table1 set column1 = replace(column1,'ú','u')
where column1 like '%ú%';
update public.table1 set column1 = replace(column1,'û','u')
where column1 like '%û%';
update public.table1 set column1 = replace(column1,'ü','u')
where column1 like '%ü%';
update public.table1 set column1 = replace(column1,'ý','y')
where column1 like '%ý%';
update public.table1 set column1 = replace(column1,'ÿ','y')
where column1 like '%ÿ%';
```

I am unsing PgAdmin 4 and need to get changed data before and after UPDATE script in TEMP table like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_change(
   Table_where_changed TEXT,
    Column_where_changed TEXT,
    Value_before_update TEXT,
    Value_after_upadate TEXT

);
```

Maybe someone did something like this before and have any example or any idea how can realize it?

Thanks a lot for any info about this! :)

Comment: What is `Table_where_changed` and `Column_where_changed` supposed to do if you only ever update `table1.column1`? And what's the primary key of `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) or by [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) :

**Trigger function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE table1_after_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
INSERT INTO temp_change (Table_where_changed, Column_where_changed, Value_before_update, Value_after_upadate)
VALUES ('table1', 'column1', OLD.column1, NEW.column1) ;
$$ ;
CREATE TRIGGER table1_after_update AFTER UPDATE OF column1 ON table1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table1_after_update() ;
```

**Rule**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE table1_after_update AS ON UPDATE TO table1
DO ALSO INSERT INTO temp_change (Table_where_changed, Column_where_changed, Value_before_update, Value_after_upadate)
        VALUES ('table1', 'column1', OLD.column1, NEW.column1) ;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! But can i specify cilumn1 in rule?

Comment: Column1 can't be specified in the rule like in the trigger function, unfortunately. This may give an advantage to the trigger function solution if it is important in your case.